# How do you import a downloaded android folder?

Tags: android, import

I downloaded the folder named AnimationDemo from https://developer.android.com/training/animation/crossfade.html

I saved it to my desktop. I opened android studio and clicked import project. I clicked on the folder once I found it on my desktop. When I opened the project, the files were there, but it was not operating correctly as I could not run it and the java files had red things on them. The run button was not green, but greyed out. How can I get this program to run or how could I import the folder correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please import project and select import destination in the same path like `desktop/AnimationDemo` then ok I think it should be working fine

Comment: delete old AnimationDemo directory and again extract in the desktop